# Sharepoint 2010 posting to a blog via email body of the post epmty

Tags: blog, incoming-email

I am trying to post to a SharePoint blog via email. It is working partially. I am able to send an email to the Blog but it only posts title of the post and body of the post is empty. Is there special format that i should use in the body of the email? I am using SharePoint server 2010.

Thanks.